# How did non-native plants find their way to Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, middle-earth

I am reading *The Return of the King*, and when I got to the chapters concerning the Battle of the Pelennor Fields, something struck me.  Earlier in the story, Theoden was shocked to see Merry and Pippin smoking "pipe-weed", which was almost unknown outside of the Shire;  intrigued, he promises Merry that they will go to Edoras and Merry can tell him about this strange habit.

> In RotK, as Theoden lays dying, he tells Merry that he regrets that he will not be able to fulfill his promise.

"Pipe-weed", of course, is tobacco.  And therein lies the problem. Since Middle-Earth is stated by Tolkien to be in a pseudo-historical, pre-historic Europe, how did non-European plants like tobacco get there before the 'modern' age? Does Tolkien provide any explanation?

Then I remembered additional examples: Bilbo served tomatoes at his party, and Sam wished he had potatoes for his rabbit stew, and then pined for fish and chips ("chips" being French fries, also made from potatoes). These are also not native to Europe.

But of course, no one in *The Lord of the Rings* seems to know that other continents exist, and I don't know of any reference to an analog of the Americas in Tolkien's legendarium.  It seems unlikely that anyone had ever traveled between Middle-earth and the Americas, to say the least.

Doing a little research, I found an entry on tomatoes at Tolkien Gateway, which states that tomatoes were also mentioned in the original version of *The Hobbit*, but Tolkien later changed the word "tomatoes" to "pickles", presumably because of the issue I am addressing here.

**Did Tolkien ever address how these plants came to Middle-earth, or admit that their presence there doesn't make much sense?**

---

*Note:  Many people have been arguing that Middle-earth is not necessarily supposed to be on our planet earth.  From Tolkien's perspective, this argument is nonsense.  I will let him address this topic in his own words (all quotes are from Tolkien's letters unless otherwise noted):*

> ‘Middle-earth’, by the way, is not a name of a never-never land without relation to the world we live in (like the Mercury of Eddison). It is just a use of Middle English middel-erde (or erthe), altered from Old English Middangeard: the name for the inhabited lands of Men ‘between the seas'. **And though I have not attempted to relate the shape of the mountains and land-masses to what geologists may say or surmise about the nearer past, imaginatively *this ‘history’ is supposed to take place in a period of the actual Old World of this planet.***

*And:*

> May I say that all this is ‘mythical’, and not any kind of new religion or vision. As far as I know it is merely an imaginative invention, to express, in the only way I can, some of my (dim) apprehensions of the world. All I can say is that, if it were ‘history’, **it would be difficult to fit the lands and events (or ‘cultures') into such evidence as we possess, archaeological or geological, concerning the nearer or remoter part of what is now called Europe; though the Shire, for instance, is *expressly stated* to have been in this region** (I p. 12).6 **I could have fitted things in with greater versimilitude, if the story had not become too far developed, before the question ever occurred to me. I doubt if there would have been much gain; and *I hope the, evidently long but undefined, gap in time between the Fall of Barad-dûr and our Days is sufficient for ‘literary credibility’, even for readers acquainted with what is known or surmised of 'pre-history'.***

*And:*

> I have, I suppose, constructed an imaginary time, **but kept my feet on my own mother-earth for place. I prefer that to the contemporary mode of seeking remote globes in ‘space’**. However curious, they are alien, and not lovable with the love of blood-kin. Middle-earth is (by the way & if such a note is necessary) not my own invention. It is a modernization or alteration (N[ew] E[nglish] D[ictionary] ‘a perversion’) of an old word for the inhabited world of Men, the oikoumenē: middle because thought of vaguely as set amidst the encircling Seas and (in the northern-imagination) between ice of the North and the fire of the South. O.English middan-geard, mediæval E. midden-erd, middle-erd. **Many reviewers seem to assume that Middle-earth is another planet!**

*And:*

> As for the shape of the world of the Third Age, I am afraid that was devised ‘dramatically’ rather than geologically, or paleontologically. **I do sometimes wish that I had made some sort of agreement between the imaginations or theories of the geologists and my map a little more possible.**

*And:*

> **I imagine the gap [between TA and now] to be about 6000 years**: that is we are now at the end of the Fifth Age, if the Ages were of about the same length as S.A. and T.A. But they have, I think, quickened; and I imagine we are actually at the end of the Sixth Age, or in the Seventh.

*And:*.

> In (5) we meet the conception of **the dragging of Tol Eressëa back eastwards across the Ocean to the geographical position of England - it becomes England (see I.26); that the part which was torn off by Ossë, the Isle of Íverin, is Ireland *is explicitly stated* in the Qenya dictionary. The promontory of Rôs is perhaps Brittany.**
>   -*The History of Eriol or Aelfwine*. [This was among the earliest writing Tolkien did regarding Middle-earth, and later, he decided against the idea of "dragging" an island to the current location of the British Isles;  instead, he chose to say that the seas eventually rose and surrounded the Shire, turning it into the British Isles]

*Were he here today, Tolkien would insist, as he frequently did during his own lifetime, that **Middle-earth is absolutely, unquestionably, without any doubt, and with complete certainty, a place in our own world, roughly analogous to a prehistoric version of modern Europe** (the LotR wiki has even produced a [map](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7718/17915439499_1faea9d95d_o_d.jpg) showing how Middle-earth and Europe would presumably align).  Arda is meant to be earth, albeit in the distant past.*

Comment: Do we actually know that pipe-weed is tobacco specifically, and not some other smokable grass like cannabis, which was definitely known in Europe in Antiquity (dare I suggest the Hobbits were regular marijuana smokers?)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - yes.  In The Hobbit, he never uses the term pipe-weed, he always says tobacco.  He also regularly calls it tobacco in LotR.  He says it is a strain of nicotiana, i.e., tobacco.  And he says the leaves are smoked;  we pot smokers smoke the buds - i.e., flowers - of the cannabis plant.

Comment: Middle Earth has elves, dwarves, hobbits, wizards, dragons, orcs, and magic rings -- but you draw the line at *potatoes*?  8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson - Yes. Tolkien explained where the elves, hobbits, dwarves, orcs, etc, came from.  He doesn't tell us where the potatoes came from.

Comment: @KeithThompson - In a way, dragons are the least implausible inhabitants of Middle-earth - we have dragons in our world today- of the Komodo variety.  They can't breathe fire or fly or talk, and they don't seem to be interested in hoarding gold and jewels, but they are still dragons.  And we used to have flying dragons too - we now call them pterosaurs or pterodactyls.  Again, they didn't talk or breathe fire or hoard gold, but they were big flying reptilian monsters.

Comment: Komodo "dragons" are dragons because we call them that. They're just big lizards. In any case, my comment above was almost entirely a joke. It's a reasonable question, I just find the situation amusing. (Elves, dwarves, dragons -- hey, wait a minute, *potatoes*??)

Comment: @KeithThompson - I took it as a joke.  As for Komodo dragons, yes, they are dragons because we call them dragons, but the same is true of Tolkien's dragons.  Things are what we call them because that is what we call them, no matter which things we are talking about.  What is a dragon if not a big lizard?

Comment: @WadCheber A worm? (in particular a long one :P)

Comment: Those Numenorians sailed all over....

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That would explain second breakfast...

Comment: @BMWurm The word _dragon_ is in origin a Greek word that means ‘snake/serpent’ (and _worm_ is the inherent Germanic word for snakes). So yeah, basically a worm.

Comment: +1 Wad, every time I reread the "nicotiana" line I cringe... good call on the solanacea, also!

Comment: Pedantic but British chips are nothing like French fries. Beyond being sliced potato

Comment: @CarlSixsmith I've been to Britain and I lived in Ireland. The chips are usually a bit thicker and less crispy, but not that different.  In any case, the point isn't about what British chips are like, only the fact that they are made from potatoes.

Comment: @WadCheber no. Order French fries from macdonalds and chips from a chippy and the texture and flavour are completely different. its like saying baked potatoes and roasted potatoes are the same. Tolkien was not referring to fries.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - Why would I order anything from McDonalds?

Comment: @WadCheber other french fry providers are available

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - So why did you mention the worst one?  :)  I'm a chef.  I know food. We have fries of all shapes, sizes, and degrees of crispness.  [Here](https://cbspittsburgh.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/french-fries-thinkstock.jpg) are some American fries.  And [here's](http://farehamtraditionalfishandchips.webs.com/fish_and_chips.jpg) British fish and chips.  I have never heard anyone try to argue that French fries are not chips, no matter what minor differences may exist between two given types of fries/chips.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are four crops in Middle-earth that shouldn't be there at first glance:

1. tomatoes
2. tobacco
3. corn
4. potatoes

Tolkien revised tomatoes out of the story (at least sometimes, I had thought always), which gets that out of the way. Possibly he considered it a mistake.

Tobacco/pipe-weed is explicitly brought over by the Númenoreans, who were great mariners who had sailed all the way around the world, both pre- and post-Fall.

> Thus it was that because of the Ban of the Valar the voyages of the Dunedain in those days went ever eastward and not westward, from the darkness of the North to the heats of the South, and beyond the South to the Nether Darkness; and they came even into the inner seas, and sailed about Middle-earth and glimpsed from their high prows the Gates of Morning in the East.

(Akallabeth)

> For the Dunedain held that even mortal Men, if so blessed, might look upon other times than those of their bodies' life; and they longed ever to escape from the shadows of their exile and to see in some fashion fee light that dies not; for the sorrow of the thought of death had pursued them over the deeps of the sea. Thus it was that great mariners among them would still search the empty seas, hoping to come upon the Isle of Meneltarma, and there to see a vision of things that were. But they found it not. And those that sailed far came only to the new lands, and found them like to the old lands, and subject to death. And those that sailed furthest set but a girdle about the Earth and returned weary at last to the place of their beginning; and they said:
>   'All roads are now bent.'

That's why it's called westmansweed. We have to assume it died out sometime later, thus explaining why Europe didn't have any in more modern times.

Corn also has a simple answer: it's not maize. It's a European cereal.

Potatoes are rather more difficult. It's possible the Númenoreans introduced those as well, but if so, it is never said. I don't believe there is any published explanation. But absent any other explanation, it's probably safest to assume that the Númenoreans brought it over, and the inhabitants of Middle-earth failed to cultivate them and they died out.

Comment: According to *Akallabêth*, corn was also brought to Middle-Earth by the Númenóreans: "the Lords of Númenor set foot again upon the western shores in the Dark Years of Men, and none yet dared to withstand them. For most of the Men of that age that sat under the Shadow were now grown weak and fearful. And coming among them the Númenóreans taught them many things. Corn and wine they brought, and they instructed Men in the sowing of seed and the grinding of grain"

Comment: @JasonBaker: Maize-corn or cereal-corn, though? According to Encyclopedia of Arda, at least *some* of the corn is definitely the cereal because of the wording: "There Treebeard sings a song of the Entwives that contains the line, 'When spring is come to garth and field, and corn is in the blade' (III 4 Treebeard). The expression 'in the blade' describes a young cereal plant that is yet to grow an ear, so we can be sure what is meant by the word 'corn'."

Comment: It's unclear, I'm by no means an agricultural expert, so it's hard for me to comment, but here's what I can find about corn: In *Fellowship*, corn in the Shire is described as "tall and full" (Book I Chapter 3); in *Two Towers*, Treebeard describes Entwives has having "hair parched by the sun to the hue of ripe corn" (III 3); a song of the Rohirrim describes corn as tall (III 6). Not sure if any of this is definitive to maize-corn. Even if that's what Tolkien means, it may just be an anachronistic word choice, for the benefit of the reader

Comment: @JasonBaker - I can't offer a conclusive answer either, but wheat grows high/tall, hair can be wheat-colored, and all cereals and grains are sometimes referred to as corn in Britain.

Comment: @WadCheber It's not just sometimes. In English English, "corn" is a generic term for any cereal crop, and never means maize specifically.

Comment: @MikeScott - +1 for "English English".  :) But I would imagine that an Englishman might call an ear of corn "corn" from time to time, or call cornmeal "cornmeal", so occasionally it must refer specifically to corn.

Comment: @Shamshiel - I did some snooping and found out that the "corn" in LotR, or at least the "corn" used to make Lembas, is almost certainly not maize.  The description Christopher Tolkien gives in the History of Middle-earth, in the "On Lembas" passage, makes this clear.  He says it was made from special corn with white stalks and was harvested without scythes or sickles.  You need neither of these to harvest maize - you can just pick the ears, and maize stalks are green, not white.  The stalks were used to weave baskets, which would be impossible with maize stalks - they are too thick.

Comment: Potatoes are referenced in the book Children of Húrin.

Comment: @MikeScott, *“In English English, "corn" is a generic term for any cereal crop, and never means maize specifically.”* — I think you’re overstating this a bit: at least for me (BrE speaker, grew up in London in the 80’s) the dominant meaning of *corn* has been *maize* my whole life (though I can well believe this varies regionally/dialectically). But in older English, and presumably for some modern speakers, it’s certainly used generically for many grains, as you say.

Answer (score 12):

Middle-Earth may represent Europe with in the context of Tolkien's work - but it is not necessarily the same Europe that we know and was around 6,000 years ago. This is covered by this other question: [How exactly is Arda supposed to be an ancient Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26808/how-exactly-is-arda-supposed-to-be-an-ancient-earth) - Tolkien's work is supposed to be a modern mythic epic, not "historical" fiction.

There are many more glaring questions to pick up on if you want to start from pipeweed and potatoes - for example, cultivation of grains and animal husbandry, iron working (even bronze working) are all more recent historically than the proposed events of Lord of the Rings - yet, we see bread, beasts of burden, swords and armour.

Comment: Tolkien made it pretty clear that the Shire eventually became the British Isles, which means that the land to the east of it became Europe.

Comment: yes, but - mythic epic - not historical

Comment: @WadCheber No, the Shire is not the British Isles, because the Shire belongs in an "imagined Earth". For example, in the British Isles there is no magic, no buried Hobbit bones, no evidence whatsoever of any of the cultures or geography described in LotR. Pipe-weed is the least of inconsistencies ;)

Comment: @AndresF. - the beginning of LotR, and Tolkien himself, disagreed with you

Comment: @WadCheber: Tolkien himself? What, he thought he was writing a history?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - No, but he did say the Shire was basically the British Isles.

Comment: "[...]imaginatively this ‘history’ is supposed to take place in a period of the actual Old World of this planet."; Letters. And of course he was working on a story set in the 'modern day' with the descendants of Numenoreans.

Comment: @AndresF.- See my notes, added in an edit.  The argument that Arda isn't meant to be the earth is completely unfounded.  Tolkien could not have been more clear on this issue.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - please see my recent edit - Tolkien himself definitively states that Arda is meant to be the earth, and Middle-earth is meant to be an ancient, prehistoric Europe. He was very clear about this subject.

Comment: @WadCheber you are right about what Tolkien states about Arda and Middle-Earth - but, he also wrote it as a mythic epic, and so was less interested in true history and geography. It's like saying Camelot and Albion are real...

Comment: @HorusKol - Except that Camelot and Albion were ideas created in a time when people didn't distinguish between history and myths the way we do.  Tolkien wrote in our own time, when we do distinguish between history and myth very clearly, but he specifically says Arda is earth.  That idea is impossible to reconcile with what we know about geology and history, but when discussing Tolkien's world, we can't ignore his own words on the subject.  We have to ignore the impossibility instead.

Comment: @HorusKol As far as your answer is concerned, Tolkien said the Third Age ended about 6,000 years ago.  On that basis, we can say that animal husbandry and cultivation of grains were not anachronistic, although we are just barely skirting anachronism (all these things would have been in their early stages 6,000 years ago, especially in Europe) but iron- and steel-working were definitely not going on in the period Tolkien is talking about.

Comment: We have to remember that the geography was different - there doesn't seem to be any separation between what we know to be separate continents - and these differences would make it easier for ideas and advances to spread.  Before the invention of large sailing ships, it was very difficult for people on different continents to communicate and share ideas.  In a world where Europe, Africa, and Asia seem to be one landmass, more or less, this would be less of an obstacle.

Comment: But Tolkien was seeking to create a mythic epic like the Arthurian and Germanic/Norse legends - not an historically and geographically accurate work. The geography is only "impossible" if you hold on to the premise that Tolkien was writing his work as historical "fact" instead of as a mythic work. Another impossibility from Tolkien's work - dragons!

Comment: @HorusKol -  I didn't say the geography is impossible, I said it is impossible to reconcile with what we know about geography and history.  But my point was that Tolkien asserted that his Arda is our earth.  We have to accept his beliefs on the subject, since it was his invention.  Also, I would say the only impossibility regarding dragons is the fire breathing.  We have Komodo dragons today, and we used to have flying reptilian things like pterodactyls and whatnot.  Tolkien's "fell worms" (a type of dragon) or whatever he called them are basically big lizards and snakes.

Comment: Yes - Tolkien said that his Arda is our Earth, but in the same way that Albion is part of Britain, or Atlantis was a real place.

Comment: Albion is the oldest known name for Britain.  It is as real as "Britain" is.

Comment: sorry - i meant Avalon

Comment: @WadCheber: fair enough, but Tolkien does also say, in those quotes that you added “ I could have fitted things in with greater verisimilitude, if the story had not become too far developed, before the question ever occurred to me. I doubt if there would have been much gain; and I hope the, evidently long but undefined, gap in time between the Fall of Barad-dûr and our Days is sufficient for ‘literary credibility’”. Sounds like a decent answer there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I didn't notice how that line related to my question.  So the answer is "Tolkien didn't think about it until he was mostly done writing, and he couldn't be bothered to go back and fix it".  :)

Comment: @WadCheber: well quite. Plus just because Hobbits had potatoes doesn’t mean we necessarily would. Stuff gets discovered and then forgotten all the time. I don’t think potatoes are particularly implausible in the context of Lord of the Rings.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - how would potatoes suddenly disappear without someone asking where they went?  Potatoes aren't implausible, but they must have been brought from somewhere or have evolved from wild ancestors that would still be extant in the region.

Comment: @WadCheber: maybe Hobbits were the only ones who cultivated them, and they died out with the Hobbits. Maybe a disease took them out.

Comment: Potato blight - Hobbits died from the ensuing famine.

Comment: The potato blight didn't affect most varieties- the Irish Lumper was the only variety that was totally wiped out, which was a disaster because it was almost the only breed in Ireland.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I don't think Tolkien wanted us to believe that Hobbits died out- I think he wanted us to believe they are as good at hiding as he says.

Comment: @WadCheber: maybe they’re equally good at hiding potatoes!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite -THOSE MIDGET BASTARDS ARE HOLDING OUT ON US!  AND THEY LET A MILLION IRISHMEN STARVE TO DEATH!  GOLLUM WAS RIGHT- HOBBITSES **ARE** EVIL!

Comment: so - you're prepared to have suspension of disbelief that there are really little people still hiding in the woods - but not that potatoes were around and then not?

Answer (score 11):

Douglas Anderson mentions this in *The Annotated Hobbit* on page 41, referring to "cold chicken and tomatoes" from the original edition being changed to "cold chicken and pickles":

> This revision brings up the question of why it should matter whether Bilbo's larder was stocked with tomatoes or pickles.  Tom Shippey, in *The Road to Middle-earth*, suggests that as Tolkien wrote the sequel to *The Hobbit*, and as he came to perceive the hobbits and their land as characteristically English in nature, he recognized tomatoes as foreign in origin and in name.  They were imports from America, like potatoes and tobacco, which were quickly adopted in England.  Though Tolkien does use the word *tobacco* in *The Hobbit* a handful of times, it is strictly avoided in *The Lord of the Rings*, where *pipeweed* is used.  There, as well, potatoes are given the more rustic name *taters*.  Tomatoes were therefore out of place in the Shire as Tolkien came to perceive it.

In short, it's something that seemed right when he first wrote it for a children's book, but as he came to think more seriously about this fictional world, he realized that these new world foods didn't strictly belong.  Unfortunately he was kind of stuck with them at that point, so he tried to wiggle out of it by giving them alternate names so you could kind of think they might be something else but similar (of course he didn't manage that completely, since Sam does call "taters" potatoes at one point in *The Two Towers*).

Personally I think that might have been about the best compromise he could have managed--Middle Earth wouldn't be quite the same with tobacco etc. removed entirely.  When it comes down to it, Middle Earth is a pseudo-medieval fantasy world, not a historical simulation, so their inclusion is forgiveable.

Comment: Great answer and +1.  There's at least one other reference to potatoes:  Sam talks about "fish and chips".

Answer (score 8):

According to the Akallabeth in The Silmarillion when Eru destroyed Numenor he turned the flat earth into a spherical one so that Numenorian sailors  living on the shores of Middle-earth now found that if they sailed far enough they would return to Middle-earth.  At that time Eru also created new continents - presumably the Americas.

I forget the exact wording but if I remember correctly there was a strong implication that in the late Second Age some of the exiles living in  Middle-earth and perhaps Elves of the Grey Havens did sail around the world and did discover the Americas.  Thus tobacco, potatoes, and tomatoes could have been imported to Middle-Earth from the Americas.

It is a mystery why and how  only the hobbits seem to have grown and smoked tobacco in more than three thousand years of the Third Age, and I do not know if other people grew tomatoes and potatoes in other lands outside the Shire.

We should hope that tomatoes and potatoes were also grown only by the hobbits in the Shire, because that would require a less terrible disaster and catastrophe at the end of the Fourth Age - when presumably the shape of lands and seas changed to that of the modern world - to wipe out all specimens in Middle-earth.

Bilbo also had a silk jacket.  There was an industry producing silk on a small scale from wild silkworms in the Mediterranean region by about the fifth century BC.  China invented the domestication of silkworms and produced silk on much larger scale.  By the time of the Roman Empire silk was being imported in large amounts thousands of  miles from Chine along the Silk Road.

So was Bilbo's silk waistcoat made from local wild silk  or imported thousands of miles from some eastern land?

Answer (score 2):

WRT pipeweed, it's only Tolkien's assumption, added in a footnote, that it was a variety of Nicotiana.  That was probably due to societal biases: tobacco use was common then, and other smokables severely frowned upon by government.  It might even be something added at the insistance of the publisher.

It seems much more likely to me that it was, in fact, some variety of cannabis.  First, because of its described effects (which in my experience, at least) are more like cannabis than tobacco.  Second, because a wise wizard ought to know the health problems tobacco would cause, and so not adopt the habit.

Comment: Problems:  1. Wizards almost certainly can't get cancer.  2. Tolkien was not what we might call "hip", and would have known almost nothing about marijuana.  3.  He began writing his stories in the early 30's, and published them in the early 50's.  When he began, pot was not widely known about outside of the jazz scene, especially among musicians.  When he finished, it was a little more popular, but still not part of the public consciousness on a large scale.  4.  Tolkien was a conservative at heart, and wouldn't have been inclined to promote use of a drug associated with the counterculture.

Comment: 5.  Tolkien smoked tobacco, usually with a pipe.  It appears that he didn't know about the health risks.  http://middle-earth.xenite.org/2012/04/24/is-pipe-weed-supposed-to-be-marijuana-or-tobacco/

Comment: 6.  He doesn't say for sure that pipe-weed is a strain of nicotiana, but says it *probably* is.  He does say with certainty that it is the *leaves* of the plant that are smoked, whereas most pot smokers, including myself, smoke the *flowers* of the cannabis plant, not the leaves.

Comment: 7.  He never explicitly describes the effects of pipe-weed, as far as I can recall, but the effects he *implies* seem to be limited to mild relaxation, which is indeed the primary effect of smoking tobacco, which I also do.

Comment: 8.  In the same paragraph as the "nicotiana" comment, Tolkien calls it "the tobacco of the Southfarthing".  9.  In The Two Towers, he says Merry "pulled out a pouch of tobacco.  10.  In The Hobbit, he uses the word "tobacco" exclusively, never "pipe-weed".

Comment: I love pot as much as anyone, but Tolkien clearly didn't intend for us to believe that pipe-weed was anything other than tobacco.

Comment: More proof of my argument - a letter from Tolkien to a pipe smoker who wrote him asking about what kind of tobacco and pipes the hobbits used: http://www.puff.com/forums/vb/general-pipe-forum/270254-letter-jrr-tolkien-pipe-weed-lotr-pipes.html

Comment: Question and answer about this subject on this very site:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/is-the-pipe-weed-in-middle-earth-somehow-intoxicating

Comment: An entire book written about the subject:  http://www.amazon.com/Pipe-Smoking-In-Middle-Earth/dp/1105429032

Comment: Note that what Tolkien thought pipeweed might be, and what it actually was could be different things.  As further evidence that it couldn't have been anything like tobacco, note that all the smokers in LOTR seem to have no difficulty going for long periods without smoking, yet suffer no withdrawal or cravings - something that is emphatically not true of any tobacco smoker I've known.  Nor does it "clear the mind of shadows".

Comment: A pipe smoker is usually not like a cigarette smoker.  It is more occasional, less frequent.  And Saruman seems to be jonesing in the Many Partings chapter.  When my Nana developed lung cancer, my Grandpa quit smoking his pipe after 70 years and never had any problems doing so.  He only smoked once every day or so anyway.  I know people who only smoke when they drink.  It happens, especially with pipe smokers.

Comment: It seems silly to suggest that Tolkien didn't know what pipe-weed was - he invented it.  He called it tobacco first.  And he himself smoked tobacco with a pipe, not marijuana.  He wrote at some length about the types of pipes hobbits used, and what kind of tobacco it was.  It was tobacco.  There can be no doubt.

Comment: And yes, as a smoker, I can assure you that a cigarette does clear my mind of shadows and allow me to tolerate annoyances more calmly.

Comment: in "Homeward Bound" Butterbur brings Gandalf and the hobbits "a wad of uncut leaf" of pipe-weed.  A tobacco leaf is huge, and must be cut before it is smoked, even if it will be used to wrap a cigar.  Marijuana leaves are small, don't come in "wads", and are not usually smoked (we pot smokers smoke the "buds", i.e., flowers, not the leaves).  Again, pipe-weed as Tolkien describes it is definitely tobacco.

Comment: Hahaha!  Nice one James.  Not to mention the not-so-subtle hints PJ made about pipeweed in the LOTR and Hobbit movies.  But seriously, I agree with Wad that he clearly meant it to be tobacco--it's what he called it initially, even.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps those plants got to Middle-earth from Númenor before it was drowned. Númenor could be equated with the Americas if you stretch your imagination enough.

On a more prosaic level, it was just an oversight on Tolkien’s part, and it would be pointless to seek a “real”, historically accurate explanation.

Comment: +1, but Numenor ceased to exist, forever.  The Americas exist.  Thus, Numenor is not the Americas

Comment: Númenór was also known as "Atalantë (the Downfallen)".  It's explicitly Atlantis, not the Americas.